# How to make row clickable in HTML table and exclude some columns and using AngularJs?

Tags: html, angularjs, modal-dialog, html-table

I have a table right here

```
   <div class="table-responsive">
        <table st-table="prijaveKvara" st-safe-src="displayedAllPrijaveKvara" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th st-sort="">Slika</th>
                    <th st-sort="datum_kvara">Datum<br />kvara</th>
                    <th st-sort="marka">Automobil</th>
                    <th st-sort="prezime">Vozač</th>
                    <th st-sort="mjesto_nastanka_stete">Mjesto nastanka<br />štete</th>
                    <th st-sort="relacija">Putni nalog</th>
                    <th st-sort="tip_kvara">Tip kvara</th>
                    <th st-sort="opis_kvara">Opis kvara</th>
                    <th st-sort="vozilo_upotrebljivo">Vozilo<br />upotrebljivo</th>
                    <th>Storniraj/<br />povratak</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="13">
                        <input st-search placeholder="global search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="kvar in prijaveKvara" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".urediPrijavaKvara" ng-click="setKvarToEditSection(kvar)">
                    <td class="openImageGallery" ng-click="addDataToGalleryModal(kvar)">
                        <div data-toggle="modal" data-target=".imageGalleryKvarVozila">
                            <span ng-if="kvar.thumbnail_slika_kvara == null">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color:red;"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-if="kvar.thumbnail_slika_kvara != null">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color:green;"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{kvar.datum_kvara_form}}</td>
                    <td><a class="tooltips">{{kvar.marka}}<br />{{kvar.model}}<span>{{kvar.registarske_oznake}}</span></a></td>
                    <td>{{kvar.ime}} {{kvar.prezime}}</td>
                    <td>{{kvar.mjesto_nastanka_stete}}</td>
                    <td><a class="tooltips">{{kvar.relacija}}<span>Napomena: {{kvar.napomena}}<br />Detalji: {{kvar.detalji}}<br />Datum početka: {{kvar.datum_pocetka_form}} <br />Datum završetka: {{kvar.datum_zavrsetka_form}} <br />Kilometraža start: {{kvar.kilometraza_start}} <br />Kilometraža kraj: {{kvar.kilometraza_kraj}}</span></a></td>
                    <td><span ng-if="kvar.tip_kvara == 1">Sudar vozila</span><span ng-if="kvar.tip_kvara == 2">Kvar na motoru</span><span ng-if="kvar.tip_kvara == 3">Ostali kvarovi</span></td>
                    <td>{{kvar.opis_kvara}}</td>
                    <td style="margin:auto;">
                        <i ng-hide="kvar.vozilo_upotrebljivo" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color:red;"></i><i ng-show="kvar.vozilo_upotrebljivo" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color:green"></i>
                    </td>
                    <td style="margin:auto;"><span ng-hide="currentVozac[0].iDvozac != kvar.iDvozac"><i ng-hide="kvar.storno" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle InsuranceAndLeasingRecordsIconsInTable" ng-click="cancelPrijavaKvaraRecord(kvar.iDkvar)"></i><i ng-show="kvar.storno" class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt InsuranceAndLeasingRecordsIconsInTable" ng-click="returnPrijavaKvaraRecord(kvar.iDkvar)"></i></span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center" colspan="13">
                        <div style="float:left;margin-top:20px;">
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="itemsByPage">
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="50">50</option>
                                <option value="100">100</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="8"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I have a function call that fills some data in modal diagram and also open that modal (it is a bootstrap). This is a peace of code

```
<tr ng-repeat="kvar in prijaveKvara" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".urediPrijavaKvara" ng-click="setKvarToEditSection(kvar)">
```

I would like to exclude this call for first and last column, but arrest of columns ( in row ) remains to call modal and the function.

Comment: use `ng-click` at cell level instead of row. Other thing could be to set unique class to those cells where you want the code to execute and check that first in your click event.

Comment: Suggest you create a directive that manages the event handling and opens the modal based on which cell was clicked within that row. You have `data-toggle="modal"` right on the row